# Graph DFS with Integer object data type returns incorrect results

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I was solving `isPathExits` between nodes from LeetCode. And for a data set, mentioned in below code the logic failed.

On investigating, I noticed when using `stack.pop();` with `Integer` datatype for the return ed node value it results `false`, If I change that return type to primitive `int` the same logic works and results `true`

Code with `Integer` return type which results false. Refer the `dfsTraverse()`

```java
public class DFScode {
    
    public static void main(String ...args) {
        int[][] edges = {{266,314},{35,276},{144,79},{242,397},{474,405},{496,110},{288,342},{480,149},{420,495},{52,385},{4,378},{490,7},{491,32},{433,479},{193,209},{342,258},{292,439},{287,281},{453,417},{422,126},{237,439},{340,325},{342,74},{129,84},{355,206},{256,161},{242,334},{114,242},{190,126},{190,455},{476,20},{209,439},{405,252},{345,231},{328,204},{405,365},{393,426},{10,488},{152,486},{170,208},{93,407},{499,439},{486,337},{473,285},{203,422},{181,474},{223,148},{273,100},{313,179},{358,290},{439,314},{75,187},{26,17},{209,137},{53,183},{197,447},{161,423},{447,368},{338,495},{117,192},{113,490},{150,423},{60,102},{447,43},{94,11},{423,334},{485,101},{155,380},{352,390},{380,206},{449,95},{345,456},{256,342},{270,124},{409,422},{107,246},{2,200},{12,58},{213,62},{429,439},{363,439},{342,174},{204,439},{211,402},{369,479},{59,49},{272,210},{449,474},{70,191},{444,265},{117,266},{439,467},{439,26},{487,495},{369,295},{273,439},{488,439},{310,405},{331,210},{356,133},{16,44},{353,439},{282,454},{469,385},{410,11},{425,438},{108,322},{336,391},{417,389},{37,183},{130,439},{56,452},{77,420},{183,351},{242,306},{6,286},{131,439},{428,144},{297,408},{342,432},{270,232},{395,369},{166,273},{216,405},{381,439},{209,448},{61,192},{224,251},{347,115},{242,468},{250,317},{140,73},{136,281},{299,345},{419,39},{167,52},{63,199},{229,236},{209,479},{215,143},{93,7},{456,439},{422,280},{355,380},{263,201},{243,0},{387,428},{190,220},{87,181},{182,40},{374,42},{439,165},{38,342},{192,143},{33,365},{320,225},{474,138},{87,21},{27,493},{466,480},{412,320},{494,180},{141,381},{9,198},{209,242},{212,318},{106,112},{378,84},{417,342},{461,401},{176,62},{295,498},{87,480},{342,469},{56,342},{405,396},{270,59},{499,372},{246,494},{349,270},{466,453},{89,411},{460,258},{59,188},{376,380},{266,126},{351,224},{209,394},{439,348},{414,405},{98,150},{395,286},{443,255},{492,19},{209,342},{37,422},{216,269},{426,255},{243,71},{238,479},{233,405},{460,275},{379,312},{403,462},{413,2},{439,428},{260,439},{162,340},{419,392},{495,439},{493,405},{369,242},{98,414},{412,270},{277,436},{384,270},{46,472},{286,410},{482,495},{480,91},{124,394},{378,424},{328,347},{85,270},{128,242},{321,149},{50,439},{439,36},{89,171},{202,459},{69,242},{342,378},{81,444},{262,470},{107,257},{86,342},{366,360},{132,374},{449,416},{364,475},{9,77},{380,172},{448,242},{136,434},{229,138},{349,9},{42,439},{395,458},{209,185},{380,5},{320,495},{149,345},{354,48},{458,147},{272,388},{272,404},{203,297},{151,239},{230,342},{380,13},{148,264},{406,201},{218,105},{429,248},{450,98},{495,357},{156,405},{439,125},{332,358},{347,113},{104,468},{234,468},{321,450},{183,439},{207,270},{59,390},{54,439},{447,459},{378,83},{359,345},{300,392},{270,171},{459,381},{153,270},{242,158},{498,277},{141,362},{390,364},{55,205},{215,434},{108,245},{209,59},{8,352},{209,454},{331,457},{242,154},{379,319},{243,416},{284,203},{156,237},{50,68},{487,366},{463,342},{485,393},{392,340},{279,103},{196,380},{250,343},{267,393},{270,191},{345,377},{211,499},{342,142},{209,225},{458,354},{371,354},{186,487},{370,236},{405,298},{313,150},{255,29},{405,436},{111,495},{216,108},{351,17},{242,406},{422,59},{342,167},{386,142},{377,242},{55,244},{405,31},{209,195},{130,342},{270,170},{178,264},{199,343},{224,374},{404,447},{359,143},{104,317},{439,189},{491,354},{291,342},{451,150},{434,166},{242,266},{439,63},{97,188},{342,445},{498,100},{51,69},{443,270},{399,342},{325,154},{197,439},{242,307},{456,283},{267,447},{440,453},{132,439},{90,439},{405,119},{17,380},{342,362},{300,94},{393,195},{137,471},{234,239},{325,452},{439,486},{362,499},{39,439},{168,270},{474,83},{203,290},{165,416},{221,439},{239,376},{439,285},{454,163},{160,59},{439,333},{342,24},{471,318},{282,497},{158,346},{188,145},{298,430},{242,368},{369,205},{207,422},{380,250},{164,468},{30,439},{98,355},{427,278},{214,195},{242,410},{354,407},{342,477},{120,354},{160,329},{439,351},{441,346},{487,85},{342,339},{66,287},{439,169},{372,127},{242,466},{405,492},{174,299},{261,497},{242,304},{249,379},{182,405},{403,371},{45,168},{497,96},{443,11},{354,225},{74,135},{333,226},{217,498},{356,33},{289,439},{450,439},{342,220},{212,155},{354,342},{99,111},{242,323},{25,342},{342,366},{439,135},{342,335},{330,38},{290,405},{441,453},{304,202},{337,490},{380,251},{87,420},{49,319},{99,380},{248,362},{42,83},{391,270},{249,242},{458,45},{287,405},{357,468},{150,209},{240,56},{400,354},{405,34},{197,299},{358,48},{439,60},{433,439},{463,452},{427,81},{401,484},{345,218},{399,469},{439,375},{445,263},{147,337},{241,439},{378,214},{405,315},{80,361},{373,246},{106,492},{401,475},{12,313},{455,272},{342,263},{326,125},{225,253},{458,208},{304,407},{58,209},{186,405},{19,400},{490,435},{151,405},{480,100},{317,190},{140,451},{462,495},{9,242},{413,292},{124,137},{330,435},{230,423},{481,358},{80,439},{431,448},{422,57},{270,311},{124,250},{247,313},{439,43},{38,52},{439,159},{268,441},{27,348},{75,358},{439,418},{114,92},{361,379},{447,274},{118,439},{219,439},{110,358},{342,3},{497,272},{358,414},{40,302},{185,436},{15,422},{435,146},{299,402},{342,413},{153,291},{467,106},{81,209},{490,35},{498,446},{490,262},{423,439},{320,41},{68,439},{408,342},{439,330},{372,440},{192,242},{26,54},{483,243},{361,467},{325,140},{377,21},{406,6},{354,170},{439,64},{6,408},{98,260},{289,213},{342,441},{242,72},{185,135},{422,334},{369,270},{405,490},{240,270},{325,347},{366,45},{422,127},{148,380},{372,64},{471,181},{63,316},{440,405},{69,20},{239,209},{308,405},{325,267},{309,386},{345,405},{427,213},{228,213},{150,288},{405,367},{342,78},{497,276},{405,123},{55,405},{439,8},{410,210},{378,405},{127,30},{497,172},{497,444},{281,79},{262,41},{387,484},{190,439},{380,33},{108,254},{207,359},{203,393},{122,347},{476,34},{353,69},{209,275},{439,470},{278,354},{205,44},{231,317},{232,421},{210,399},{109,405},{352,108},{448,498},{16,204},{197,418},{352,119},{235,494},{0,59},{342,140},{342,430},{166,380},{289,190},{227,67},{310,378},{52,378},{80,85},{484,85},{244,380},{320,176},{104,451},{162,490},{209,47},{405,301},{95,378},{279,354},{490,234},{82,200},{246,444},{244,379},{159,51},{194,341},{274,405},{324,474},{385,458},{41,422},{411,354},{217,386},{28,441},{18,380},{402,226},{136,403},{96,133},{333,132},{327,486},{342,257},{298,398},{242,393},{72,161},{144,315},{154,446},{303,439},{79,66},{98,87},{196,353},{337,8},{488,159},{439,255},{124,281},{129,383},{153,289},{439,421},{439,324},{245,473},{155,20},{469,119},{398,498},{384,480},{133,495},{403,172},{355,93},{112,342},{397,90},{405,248},{159,428},{228,370},{92,439},{494,380},{121,439},{23,498},{62,321},{96,241},{380,77},{337,351},{387,460},{439,144},{79,342},{76,340},{270,22},{480,287},{176,378},{252,59},{92,179},{368,57},{101,322},{132,182},{471,378},{64,362},{219,319},{347,193},{430,139},{226,321},{67,304},{89,439},{67,346},{431,11},{59,325},{10,339},{129,276},{136,439},{4,168},{441,94},{326,342},{270,185},{439,305},{439,370},{88,434},{62,40},{346,356},{451,345},{412,351},{106,466},{76,439},{160,82},{187,211},{113,471},{209,66},{157,278},{164,342},{486,148},{389,139},{39,298},{354,245},{89,212},{103,22},{144,251},{60,242},{378,481},{376,417},{390,203},{332,24},{459,318},{342,401},{341,80},{182,257},{115,405},{238,414},{379,238},{198,439},{70,367},{224,422},{16,314},{13,488},{386,486},{2,0},{490,341},{273,88},{142,311},{460,472},{297,342},{454,131},{435,383},{425,442},{131,147},{455,401},{434,73},{97,405},{223,342},{440,194},{273,71},{405,141},{405,161},{105,242},{378,359},{439,309},{378,383},{27,463},{443,327},{186,342},{439,91},{406,455},{451,175},{317,288},{230,111},{405,103},{32,430},{229,295},{383,102},{167,298},{440,23},{380,322},{466,165},{205,265},{63,95},{317,43},{44,323},{181,439},{439,51},{293,379},{107,266},{476,170},{74,231},{242,437},{155,170},{5,0},{180,124},{357,386},{101,405},{73,422},{420,423},{3,200},{12,156},{80,170},{0,23},{382,439},{62,0},{41,46},{307,358},{457,447},{373,426},{439,157},{380,231},{206,14},{451,439},{145,495},{85,243},{357,374},{21,242},{47,202},{322,237},{439,294},{14,439},{0,408},{25,462},{242,272},{163,479},{341,218},{487,497},{439,296},{95,326},{439,489},{62,215},{327,334},{402,393},{67,479},{117,50},{295,473},{392,272},{209,177},{75,94},{208,62},{80,459},{272,175},{439,271},{284,430},{424,97},{490,437},{49,439},{214,369},{273,462},{336,398},{106,229},{228,23},{228,497},{146,439},{45,85},{439,302},{133,498},{465,405},{2,254},{489,233},{498,235},{441,32},{100,281},{335,354},{369,463},{439,284},{319,110},{425,378},{252,352},{324,350},{430,85},{374,342},{1,458},{380,325},{29,242},{322,268},{65,133},{41,457},{106,257},{304,201},{173,439},{65,439},{30,141},{4,385},{242,85},{208,414},{199,296},{178,405},{116,62},{134,378},{459,439},{338,292},{215,494},{284,177},{341,229},{439,227},{227,141},{247,242},{439,139},{242,317},{102,323},{46,51},{393,306},{380,16},{439,419},{228,410},{55,176},{401,280},{18,275},{209,229},{342,61},{108,342},{369,316},{72,457},{353,116},{238,267},{285,7},{9,48},{133,52},{326,29},{211,59},{259,342},{50,227},{222,354},{246,380},{478,426},{342,194},{60,72},{313,276},{58,241},{45,211},{496,380},{326,178},{443,485},{41,379},{285,98},{265,342},{367,371},{88,351},{143,255},{373,405},{350,405},{0,41},{75,176},{236,13},{264,405},{363,494},{272,87},{165,204},{390,36},{212,2},{117,378},{464,439},{328,55},{447,78},{281,275},{405,218},{344,393},{256,314},{439,269},{356,59},{224,111},{493,95},{374,445},{184,439},{277,180},{77,85},{391,299},{64,67},{270,494},{476,369},{473,325},{149,313},{53,59},{391,454},{307,351},{207,317},{232,409},{52,94},{343,272},{405,70},{439,143},{448,415},{240,496},{439,332},{261,156},{183,64}};
        
        DFScode d = new DFScode();
        System.out.println(d.validPath(500,edges,217,308));
        //System.out.println(d.validPath(500,edges,308,405));
    }

    public boolean validPath(int n, int[][] edges, int source, int destination) {
        Map<Integer,List<Integer>> g = buildGraph(edges);
        return dfsTraverse(g,source,destination);
    }

    public Map<Integer,List<Integer>> buildGraph(int[][] edges){

        Map<Integer,List<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<edges.length;i++){
            graph.putIfAbsent(edges[i][0], new ArrayList<>());
            graph.putIfAbsent(edges[i][1], new ArrayList<>());

            graph.get(edges[i][0]).add(edges[i][1]);
            graph.get(edges[i][1]).add(edges[i][0]);
        }
        return graph;

    }   

    public boolean dfsTraverse (Map<Integer,List<Integer>> graph, Integer fromVertex, Integer toVertex) {

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();

        stack.push(fromVertex);
        while(!stack.empty()) {
            Integer currentVertex = stack.pop();
            if(currentVertex == toVertex) return true;
            if(visited.contains(currentVertex)) continue;
            visited.add(currentVertex);
            for(Integer neighbor: graph.get(currentVertex)) {
                    stack.push(neighbor);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Same logic of `dfsTraverse()` but with primitive `int` used for `stack.pop()`..

- Below is the code returns `true`.

```java
    public boolean dfsTraverse (Map<Integer,List<Integer>> graph, Integer fromVertex, Integer toVertex) {

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();

        stack.push(fromVertex);

        while(!stack.empty()) {
            int currentVertex = stack.pop();  // changed Intger to int 
            if(currentVertex == toVertex) return true;
            if(visited.contains(currentVertex)) continue;
    
            visited.add(currentVertex);
            for(int neighbor: graph.get(currentVertex)) { //Changed Integer to int
                stack.push(neighbor);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am not sure what could be wrong using Integer. Any insights?

Comment: You can't compare `Integer` objects with `==`, you must use `equals()`.  The fact that it works for _some_ `Integer`s is an internal optimization.

Comment: True.. it makes sense. it totally slipped my brain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @jim Garrison. using object equals fixed the issue.

```
  if(currentVertex.equals(toVertex)) return true;
```